# Prove that the field $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ is not algebraically closed where $p$ is prime

Tags: field-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

How would you go about proving that the field $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ is not algebraically closed where $p$ is prime?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the polynomial $f\in \Bbb F_p$ be given as
$$
f(x) = x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots (x-p+1)
$$
Then $f(a) = 0$ for any $a \in \Bbb F_p$. Thus $g(x) = f(x) + 1$ has no roots in $\Bbb F_p$, and therefore $\Bbb F_p$ has a non-trivial algebraic extension obtained by adjoining all the roots of $g$.

The same proof (with minor changes to the definition of $f$) goes for *any* finite field, not just the ones of prime order. This shows that a finite field can never be algebraically closed.

Comment: Thank you so much @Arthur! You far exceeded my expectations as to the help I would receive, thank you very much indeed!